# jQuery Opera focus event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opera

There is a search input and a complex drop-down div under it. 
The script shows the div when focus is on the input.

It works fine everywhere except in Opera. 
In Opera when I focus the input, nothing happens. But, if I click on another desktop application, like checking my mail, and then go back to the website, the drop-down on the website suddenly shows.

What is a way to fix this?

```
function checkSf() {
    if ($('#search-field').val() != "" || $('#search-field').is(":focus")){
        $('.search-dropdown').show();
    } 
}
$('#search-field').keyup(function(){
    checkSf()
});

$('#search-field').on('focus', function(){
    checkSf()
});
```

Comment: I don't get the logic checking for `$('#search-field').is(":focus")` on element keyup and focus events. In both cases, the element is focused. That's said, i'd try to use a timeout, maybe just an event stack issue on Opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy i found an answer.
This bug is the same as in safari and chrome.
To fix this i've added a zero timeout.

Strangely it worked.

```
function checkSf() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($('#search-field').val() != "" || $('#search-field').is(":focus")){
            $('.search-dropdown').show();
        } 
    },0);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your Javascript and JQuery looks okay. Is your HTML set up something like this. If so, this works for me.

```
<input type="text" id="search-field" />

<select id="ddlSearch" class="search-dropdown" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```